# Laravel won't preform vendor:publish correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have installed a package and went trough all the necessary steps of setting the package

Via composer

```
composer require jasekz/laradrop
```

Then in your config/app.php add

```
'Jasekz\Laradrop\LaradropServiceProvider'
```

to the providers array.

Then run

```
 artisan vendor:publish
```

followed by

```
 artisan migrate
```

And when I run vendor:publish the content of the assets file is not copied from package

Comment: Have you tried asking the developer of this package?

Answer (score 1):

just do this at cmd by typing `php artisan vendor:publish`